# Setting ItemsControl DataTemplate binding fields at runtime

Tags: wpf, datatemplate, itemscontrol

I've this XAML:

```
<ItemsControl>
    <ItemsControl.ItemTemplate>
        <DataTemplate>
            <local:Column YControl="{Binding YData}" />
        </DataTemplate>
    </ItemsControl.ItemTemplate>
</ItemsControl>
```

How set YData variable name with a string at runtime ?

Comment: Excuse me, what's your purpose? Why you need to change a property name you are binding to?

Comment: This code is part of a usercontrol, the property name I'm binding to is an external parameter

Answer (score 1):

You can create the binding dynamically in C#:

```
<ItemsControl>
    <ItemsControl.ItemTemplate>
        <DataTemplate>
            <local:Column Initialized="SetYControlBinding_OnColumnInitialized"/>
        </DataTemplate>
    </ItemsControl.ItemTemplate>
</ItemsControl>
```

Code Behind:

```
void SetYControlBinding_OnColumnInitialized(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
   var control = (Column)sender;
   var binding = ...
   control.SetBinding(Column.YControlProperty, binding);
}
```